Cannot view analysis plots in Ansys ACP
As you can see there is no plot appears after I press apply button how can I fix it ? and is there a way to force it to appear by putting a line of python ?
Analysis tab of woven fabric
I tried to reinstall ansys and reset the program but nothing works
